# Set specific order for PrimeFaces multiple fileupload

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

How do I set a specific order of files to be uploaded by the `<p:fileUpload>` component that uses a listener ?

```
<p:fileUpload id="mfu"
              widgetVar="mfu"
              fileUploadListener="#{fileBean.uploadImages}" 
              mode="advanced"
              dragDropSupport="true"
              multiple="true"/>
```

My specific requirement is that I want to upload a .CSV File, parse it and save it into the database, and after that I need to upload .JPEG files, and then save them into the same table. So it has to be done in a specific sequence. .CSV files first, then .JPEG images.

Any ideas would be beneficial.

EDIT : All files have to be uploaded together (One time, multiple files)

Comment: Why not use the allowed filetypes, set that to csv first and after uploading change it to jpg.

Comment: Why do you btw expect or at least think this kind of specific business logic would be supported by a generic component?

Comment: Well it seems like it is not available out of the box. Could you suggest anything else ?


You mean to say that at first it should be set as `"csv"` and later it should be uploaded to `"jpeg"`. Assuming that this would be done from the Bean, at which point in the listener should I make the change ?


If you are suggesting that first I should upload csv and then upload jpeg, these are TWO separate actions. I am trying to combine int ONE.

Comment: So you want to allow uploading all files at once (which is not as you describe in your question), and need to process them in a specific order and want the upload component to do that for you? No chance... Just upload all files, store them in a temporary folder and start processing in the right order. No component will do this for you.

Comment: you can follow the @Kukeltje approach or simple you can put validation for file upload like check if CSV data(PK) is there in DB table or not and then allowed to JPEG file upload. Hope this will solve your problem.